# disable programmatically "volume key shortcut"

Tags: java, android

I need to **disable** programmatically the option `volume key` shortcut available in  `Settings`->`Accessibility`->`Volume key shortcut`, see the link below- https://support.google.com/accessibility/android/answer/6006966?hl=en.

This option actives a shortcut when you press both `volume` `keys` for **3 seconds** to start an accessibility tool. This option can be turned off manually, but I need to **turn off it programmatically**. Is there a way to do this?

Thank you

Answer (score 0):

I found this command (Android oreo 8.1):

```
adb shell settings put secure accessibility_shortcut_enabled 0
```